# Why follow standards of a voluntary organization?

Tags: software, standards, standardization

I'm struggling to understand how, for example, the [IETF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Engineering_Task_Force) is a "standards organization" but the standards are "voluntary" meaning there is no civil or criminal penalties for not following the standards.

I don't understand how those are standards. Why would anyone follow them?

Comment: Network effects *are* penalties. Those who ignore the way other people do things have a higher cost of participation in common markets, and the absolutely last thing an enterprise wants is unnecessary costs.

Comment: Even in the cases where you can be sued for negligence by not following a standard, such as building standards, electrical codes or avionics software, it's rarely the organisation setting the standard who sues, rather the aggrieved party or the government does. That isn't what standards setting organisations do.

Comment: Why would anyone listen to what a dictionary has to say?

Comment: @candied_orange "Stable Genius" would not listen to a dictionary and covefefe was the result.

Comment: I'm going out on a limb and voting to reopen this question. I changed the phrasing of the title and body text to focus more on the organization and standards. Still on the fence about this being opinion-based, but at least the question doesn't just sound like a complaint now.

Comment: Standards such as those that the IETF publishes are made to make interoperability possible. They are not standards that ensure for example safety or quality. Not following the IETF's standards does not make your software dangerous or unsafe, it just means it won't work with other software. I would find it quite absurd if I should be regarded as a criminal just because I wrote some software that uses a non-standard protocol - while it would be reasonable to expect that I would be liable if I would build a house that is not according to safety standards.

Comment: You're mixing up different meanings of the word "standards".

Comment: @candied_orange the English dictionary reflects how people talk, not the other way around. It is the same with these so called "standards" that nobody (not even major websites) actually follow. They only real "standard" is using correct code that the browser can parse. I mean programmers even use the word REST wrong.

Comment: @JuanPerez right, because no one ever learned anything about how to talk by reading the dictionary.

Answer (score 10):

[Network effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_effect), almost literally in the case of the IETF. There's little point me building an "e-mail" client if it can't communicate with people using a different client. There's little point me building a "web browser" if it can't connect to Google.

Comment: You can easily connect to Google or send emails without following standards. Furthermore, many apps are only interested in communicating between their own back and front

Answer (score 7):

To expand on the other answers, there are two basic aspects:

- the IETF is its members, who are in practice staff of major companies working on key parts of internet administration, hardware, and software. That is, development doesn't follow the IETF, the IETF follows development.
- there are advantages to coordination. It doesn't matter whether everyone in a country drives on the left or the right, but it *does* matter that they all make the same choice!

The IETF has always operated on the principle of ["rough consensus and running code"](https://www.ietf.org/how/runningcode/). Solutions are often built first by one organization, then a publication is made about them, then other implementations that work with the first one are made. It does not call its standards "standards", instead "requests for comments", reflecting their non-binding status.

The benefit of following the RFCs is that your software is more likely to work properly with software written by other people who are reading the same RFCs. The nearest thing to "enforcement" is purely social; if you don't follow the relevant RFCs and this causes problems, you will be blamed, resulting in senior engineers being rude about you or your company on mailing lists.

Comment: i'm still struggling to understand, do you have a discord or reddit? i can't privately message you on stackexchange for whatever reason, but if you have a discord please you or anyone that can answer my question message me How To Linux#6752

Comment: I've been on here for a decade and had no idea it was even possible to PM people? Anyway, the place to discuss questions on StackExchange is on the question itself, because in theory this answer should be able to help more than just one person. Re: understanding; I don't understand what you don't understand, unfortunately.

Comment: i don't understand why the big tech companies would listen to the IETF, i'm simply not getting it, i could explain to this to you in five minutes on a discord call, but if you want to spend days on this comment thread i can do that to i guess but i only have 339 characters left, so its very hard to explain my position because the questions are difficult to articulate.

Comment: @HowToLinux one of the reasons why the Stackexchange process for downvoting, editing and generally battering questions exists is that articulating the question is important work - and sometimes articulating the question causes the answer to fall out.

Comment: @HowToLinux You've got a bunch of reasons in these answers. Edit into your question what you understand about these reasons. Having defined what you do understand, you may find it easier to express what you don't understand. If nothing else, it will help us to know what not to explain further.

Comment: > one of the reasons why the Stackexchange process for downvoting, editing and generally battering questions exists is that articulating the question is important work - and sometimes articulating the question causes the answer to fall out.

that's just a bunch of pedantic nonsense, sometimes the best way to articulate the question and get the best answers is through another better form of communication like speaking on voice via discord, because this text stuff ain't working for me, i'm glad it works for you but it ain't for me.

Comment: I love the way a lack of  standard agreement (stackexchange vs discord) leads to miscommunication while all answers claim that standards are made for interoperability.

Comment: @HowToLinux if they don't follow the IETF their software won't work on the internet and nobody will buy it. Note that Google didn't follow the IETF in Chrome. Google designed their own protocol that Google's browser used to talk to Google's websites. They still had to support HTTP on both sides so non-Google browsers could use Google websites, and Google browsers could use non-Google websites. (Then they submitted this protocol to the IETF so everyone else could use it - but they didn't have to)

Comment: @pjc50 i don't understand your answer. If you want to communicate with a website you look for their API, and follow its instructions like `firebase.signInWithGoogle()` or whatever. Why would I care about any standards? I just follow the documentation of that service and that's it. If I want someone to use my webapp they can look at my docs/API, just like they do. Besides, relying on standards forces all sites to be tight coupled together which is a terrible idea

Answer (score 6):

Businesses and organizations follow voluntary standards when it is to their own advantage. For communication standards like the TCP/IP protocol the advatage is quite obvious - if you don't follow the standard it will not be able to communicate with other parties on the internet. Nobody would buy or use a networked product that was not able to communicate over the network!

But there are many examples where a business chooses not to follow a standard. This is usually because the business has enough market dominance to be able to dictate its own de-facto standards or proprietary solution. For example Microsoft pushing proprietary solutions like ActiveX or Silverlight rather than supporting web standards back when Internet Explorer was reigning. But this only works as long as you have overwhelming market dominance.

Any business would prefer to able to dictate a proprietary standard they control. But they would hate even more for any competitor to be able to do the same! Therefore vendor-neutral standard bodies tend to be successful in domains with many competitors and where no single party is strong enough to dictate the rules. So it is in the self-interest of everybody to follow vendor-neutral standards.

Comment: > But there are many examples where a business chooses not to follow a standard.

can you provide an example? thank you

Comment: @HowToLinux Apple's refusal to use the same connectors as everyone else

Comment: Is there a case where it is better to not use an existing standard?

Comment: @moonman239 what do you mean by better? Presumably it's better *for Apple* that they act that way

Comment: @Caleth Like, is there a case where it might be more profitable in the long run to develop and/or use a proprietary standard? Like, maybe I'd look at an existing standard , decide that its shortfalls are unacceptable and then develop my own proprietary standard that I can then turn around and market to the end-user: "SMTP has a major vulnerability that my standard doesn't. Use my products if you care about security!"

Comment: @moonman239: Nobody would use a SMTP server which could not send or receive emails from other SMTP servers on the internet.

Comment: Apple, Sun, Seagate, others, have a long history of creating new connectors, but they publish their design so it becomes a standard, rather than being proprietary.  The advantage of using a non-standard connector or creating a new standard is that the new one does something the old one didn't.

Comment: i'm still not fundamentally understanding why a giant tech company would listen to the IETF, i'm still not understanding what role they play, the 5 big tech companies have a practical monopoly on tech, microsoft, google, facebook, amazon, and apple, why would they listen to the IETF? why wouldn't they just get together every now and then and decide on standards themselves? why use the IETF?

Comment: @HowToLinux: This is kind of what happened with web standards. The browser vendors Apple, Google and Mozilla got tired of W3C and created WHATWG as an alternative standards organization. Together they had enough power to make WHATWG the de-facto web standards body. But this was possible because there is only a handful of significant browser vendors. It would be much more difficult with the IETF standards since you also need to get network hardware vendors on board.

Comment: @HowToLinux: ...but the question is, why would they? If everyone is reasonably satisfied with IETF, why create an alternative organization? Each party may hope to get more influence in a new organization, but then they also risk a competitor getting critical influence.

Comment: @HowToLinux have a look at e.g. https://www.ietf.org/blog/quic-industry/ and note the names. The group in which the big five get together and decide what standards to use is .. the IETF. QUIC was developed *first* by Google and *then* became an IETF standard.

Answer (score 1):

Voluntary standards can still be made mandatory in a contract between two parties. A party that does not adhere to the standard can then be sued for a breach of contract.

To lawyers, this makes perfect sense. Instead of adding a lot of very complicated technical language to a legal document, they just reference a clearly identified external standard for the technical content.

Comment: .. however, I've not heard of this happening in relation to IETF standards? I have heard of it in relation to FIPS, though.

Comment: @pjc50: Most contracts are private between the contracting parties, especially between businesses. You'd be unlikely to hear about their terms.

Answer (score 0):

Potential customers care about interoperability.

As an analogy, afaict, there are no civil or criminal penalties for making and selling a toaster that operates on 80V 30Hz AC power, with a 4 pin plug, as long as it was marketed as such.

No-one is going to buy such a toaster, even if it is the greatest toaster ever, for the least cost, because they can't plug it into the sockets in their kitchen.

Comment: Not a great analogy, since that goes into the thorny area of CE marking, but the principle of not being able to plug into other things is sound. Works a little differently for computer standards such as USB and HDMI, who do it by trademark enforcement.

Comment: Just a note: The United States government (Federal Communications Commission, if I recall correctly) sets the standard voltage at 120V. So there may (or may not) be legal issues with selling your toaster to US consumers.

Comment: @moonman239 other countries have different standard voltages, I just made up one that's different from them all. You can take a UK toaster to the US and sell it to a toaster collector

Comment: @moonman239 FCC does no such thing.  They regulate communication standards like radio and phone lines.  Perhaps you are thinking FTC -- but they likely would not get involved except for false advertising.  Or maybe the consumer protection arm of FTC if it caught on fire.

Comment: Also, there's no reason you couldn't sell your toaster with the goofy plug and an adapter that had the relevant converters in it.   I've got half a dozen devices from different manufacturers that all want 18v DC, and they come with this brick shaped adapter in the middle of their power cord...

Comment: @pjc50 nothing stops you putting a USB connector on your product that delivers 20 volts instead of 5 volts (I wanted to say 120 volts but it may cause problems with the insulation of your connector), on the data lines, and the empty space in the connector also carries a stream of good old H2O. You might not be allowed to *call* it USB but everyone with half a brain will see it fits in a USB port.

Comment: yeah, the only thing you're prevented from doing is using the logo, which is what I meant by trademark enforcement. https://www.usb.org/logo-license